# Current time of other cities

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

Is it possible to get current time of other cities from code?(for example current time of Paris)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to get it:

```
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CEST"]];
NSLog(@"Paris time: %@", [[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale:nil ]);
```

Comment: A list of timezone abbreviations is available here: http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/

Comment: and NSTimeZone supports 48 out of those 250 abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [NSTimeZone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html).